# How to check all previous checkbox in angular 6

Tags: angular, checkbox, input

When i click on a checkbox i would like to check all the previous checkbox and uncheck all the next one, how could i achieve this ?

Here how i generate my checkboxes

```
<div *ngFor="let check of feature.tests; let i = index" class="col-md-12">
    <mat-checkbox>{{check.name}}</mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

EDIT: With jquery i achieve this by doing something like

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {
  $(this).prevAll().prop('checked', true);
  $(this).nextAll().prop('checked', false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the change attribute to mat-checkbox, something like this

```
<mat-checkbox (change)="checkboxChanged($event.checked, i)"></mat-checkbox>
```

where checkboxChanged is a method in your typescript:

```
changeCheckbox(checked, index) {
 if(checked)
    {
      for(let i = 0; i < index; i++)
      {
        checkboxes[i] = true;
      }
      [...etc]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/check-all-ckeck)

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let check of feature; let i = index" class="col-md-12">
<mat-checkbox [checked]="i <= finalC" (change)="checkAll($event.checked, i)">{{check.name}}</mat-checkbox>
```

TS:

```
  finalC: number = -1;
  constructor() {
  }

  feature: Array<any> = [
    { name: 'checkbox 1' },
    { name: 'checkbox 2', },
    { name: 'checkbox 3', },
    { name: 'checkbox 4', }]

  checkAll(c, i: number) {

    if (c) {
      this.finalC = i
    } else {
      this.finalC = i - 1
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response the problem is that i have multiple tabs containing multiple checkbox and with your method it also check the checkboxes that are in other tabs, i would like that it check only the previous checkboxes that are in the tab

Comment: can u create stack blitz i cant assume tabs??

Comment: here an image of my object and app https://imgur.com/a/QXHZRiV every item is a form, every feature is a tab of the form and every tests is a checkbox in the tab

Comment: you can capture index of tab. or just create stack blitz for demo.

Comment: I'll create a stackblitz with my objects, it may take a little long